# External link is blocked

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a question about my quick and dirty solution for displaying a clickable icon in my wordpress header. I just want to a a quick icon to open a external link so i add the following line to my template.php file:

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( "http://www.google.com/" ); ?>" rel="external" class="site-intro"><i class="fab fa-github-alt fa-2x"> </i></a>
```

I spotted the region where my header will be initiated and will be styled. The icon will be shown as I wanted it to be but I can not click the link...
When I change the link to my home URL or use 'home_url' the icon is clickable. But when I use an external link I get the blocking sign when I hover over the link.

Might anyone know why this is happening?

```
/**
 * Site title
 * Displays the gravatar, site title and description
 * Hooked into highwind_header()
 * @since 1.0
 */
if ( ! function_exists( 'highwind_site_title' ) ) {
    function highwind_site_title() {
        ?>
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home" class="site-intro">
            <?php
                do_action( 'highwind_site_title_link' );
                if ( apply_filters( 'highwind_header_gravatar', true ) ) {
                    echo get_avatar( apply_filters( 'highwind_header_gravatar_email', $email = esc_attr( get_option( 'admin_email' ) ) ), 256, '', esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name' ) ) );
                }
            ?>

            <h1 class="site-title"><?php esc_attr( bloginfo( 'name' ) ); ?></h1>
            <h2 class="site-description"><?php esc_attr( bloginfo( 'description' ) ); ?>
            </h2>
        </a>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( "http://www.google.com/" ); ?>" rel="external" class="site-intro"><i class="fab fa-github-alt fa-2x"></i></a>
    <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a PHP echo command for a URL where you already know the value and you're not using a variable?  Seems pointless and adds more bytes to page load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change double quote to single quote.

```
<?php echo esc_url( 'http://www.google.com/' ); ?>
```

As:

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( 'http://www.google.com/' ); ?>" rel="external" class="site-intro">
<i class="fab fa-github-alt fa-2x"> </i>
</a>
```